# Matching words with exactly one vowel

Tags: regex, perl

I want to match only the strings that have exactly one vowel.

I tried this code, and it works but it also matches those strings that haven't any vowels (for example `hshs`, `ksks`, `lslsl`) and I need only the strings that have just one vowel

```
if ( $string !~ /\*w[aeiou]\w*[aeiou]\W*/ ) {
   print $string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tr///` to count the occurrences of letters in a string.

Something like this perhaps

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $string ( qw/ a fare is paid for every cab /) {

  if ( $string =~ tr/aeiuoAEIOU// == 1 ) {
     print $string, "\n";
  }

}
```

**output**

```
a
is
for
cab
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple, at least one vowel:

```
if ($string =~ /[aeiou]/i) {
   print $string;
}
```

exactly one vowel:

```
if ($string =~ /^[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$/i) {
   print $string;
}
```